# how to use like function in collection

Tags: laravel, controller, sql-like

i have trouble where i need to use where like orwhere like function in collection but it didn't work
here's my query

```
$data = Unit::with([
            // mendapatkan relasi skpd
            'program.kegiatan.subKegiatan.rekening' => fn ($query) => $query->where('level', 9),
            'penyedia',
            'swakelola',
        ])
            ->whereNull('induk_id') // hanya mengambil induk (skpd)
            ->orderBy('kode', 'desc')
            ->get()->transform(function ($item) use ($filters) {

                // ambil upt
                $sub = Unit::with([
                    'program.kegiatan.subKegiatan.rekening' => fn ($query) => $query->where('level', 9),
                    'penyedia',
                    'swakelola',
                ])
                ->orderBy('kode', 'desc')
                ->when($filters == 'false', fn ($query) => $query->where('induk_id', NULL))
                ->where('induk_id', $item->id)
                ->orWhere('id', $item->id)
                ->get();

                return [
                    'id' => $item?->uuid,
                    'skpd_id' => $item?->id,
                    'nama' => $item?->nama,
                    'kode' => $item?->kode,
                    'filter' => $filters,
                    'pagu' => $pagu = $sub?->pluck('program')->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()->sum('jumlah'),
                    //IDEN APBD
                    'iden_p_apbd' => $iden_p_apbd = $sub?->pluck('program')->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()
                                                            ->where('kode_rekening', 'NOT LIKE', '%'.'5.1.03'.'%')
                                                            ->where('kode_rekening', 'NOT LIKE', '%'.'5.1.04'.'%')
                                                            ->where('kode_rekening', 'NOT LIKE', '%'.'5.1.05'.'%')
                                                            ->where('kode_rekening', 'NOT LIKE', '%'.'5.1.06'.'%')
                                                            ->where('kode_rekening', 'NOT LIKE', '%'.'5.2.01'.'%')
                                                            ->sum('jumlah'),
                    'iden_np_apbd' => $iden_np_apbd = $sub?->pluck('program')->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()
                                                                ->where('level', 'LIKE', '%'.'9'.'%')
                                                            ->where('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '%'.'5.1.03'.'%')
                                                            ->where('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '%'.'5.1.04'.'%')
                                                            ->where('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '%'.'5.1.05'.'%')
                                                            ->where('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '%'.'5.1.06'.'%')
                                                            ->where('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '%'.'5.2.01'.'%')
                                                            ->sum('jumlah'),
                    'iden_g_apbd' => $iden_g_apbd = $sub?->pluck('program')->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()
                                    ->where('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '%'.'5.1.01'.'%')->sum('jumlah'),
                    //IDEN PAKET
                    'iden_p' => $iden_p = $sub?->pluck('program')->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()->where('metode', "p")->sum('jumlah'),
                    'iden_s' =>$iden_s = $sub?->pluck('program')->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()->where('metode', "s")->sum('jumlah'),
                    'iden_np' => $iden_np = $sub?->pluck('program')->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()->where('metode', "np")->sum('jumlah'),
                    'iden_g' => $iden_g = $sub?->pluck('program')->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()->where('metode', "g")->sum('jumlah'),
                    'iden_noiden' => $sub?->pluck('program')->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()->where('metode', "")->sum('jumlah'),                    
                    'total_iden' => ($iden_p + $iden_s + $iden_np + $iden_g),

                    // sub skpd (upt)
                    'sub' => $sub?->transform(fn ($upt) => [
                        'id' => $upt?->id,
                        'induk_id' => $upt?->induk_id,
                        'nama' => $upt?->nama,
                        'kode' => $upt?->kode,
                        'filter' => $filters,
                        'pagu' => $pagu = $upt?->program?->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()->sum('jumlah'),
                        //IDEN APBD
                        'iden_p_apbd' => $upt->program?->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()
                        // 'iden_p_apbd' => $iden_p_apbd = $upt?->program?->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()
                                                                            ->where('metode', 'like', 'np')
                                                                            ->orWhere('kode_rekening', 'NOT LIKE', '%5.1.03%')
                                                                            ->orWhere('kode_rekening', 'NOT LIKE', '%5.1.04%')
                                                                            ->orWhere('kode_rekening', 'NOT LIKE', '%5.1.05%')
                                                                            ->orWhere('kode_rekening', 'NOT LIKE', '%5.1.06%')
                                                                            ->orWhere('kode_rekening', 'NOT LIKE', '%5.2.01%')
                                                                            ->sum('jumlah'),

                        'iden_np_apbd' => $iden_np_apbd = $upt?->program?->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()
                                                                        ->where('level', 'LIKE', '%'.'5.1.03'.'%')
                                                                        ->orWhere('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '%5.1.04%')
                                                                        ->orWhere('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '%5.1.05%')
                                                                        ->orWhere('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '%5.1.06%')
                                                                        ->orWhere('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '%5.2.01%')
                                                                        ->sum('jumlah'),
                        'iden_g_apbd' => $iden_g_apbd = $upt?->program?->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()
                                                                        ->where('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '%'.'5.1.01'.'%')->sum('jumlah'),
                        //IDEN PAKET
                        'iden_p' => $iden_p = $upt?->program?->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()->where('metode', "p")->sum('jumlah'),
                        'iden_s' => $iden_s = $upt?->program?->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()->where('metode', "s")->sum('jumlah'),
                        'iden_np' => $iden_np = $upt?->program?->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()->where('metode', "np")->sum('jumlah'),
                        'iden_g' => $iden_g = $upt?->program?->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()->where('metode', "g")->sum('jumlah'),
                        'iden_noiden' => $upt?->program?->flatten()->pluck('kegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('subKegiatan')->flatten()->pluck('rekening')->flatten()->where('metode', "")->sum('jumlah'),
                        'total_iden' => ($iden_p + $iden_s + $iden_np + $iden_g)
                    ])->sortBy('kode')->where('pagu', '!=', 0)->values(),
                ];
            })->sortBy('kode')->where('pagu', '!=', 0)->values();
```

it seems ->where('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '%'.'5.1.03'.'%') not work at all is there other method other than using this?
because in my table i have field kode_rekening which the values is 5.1.03.xxxxx, 5.1.02.xxxxx, etc and i want to use like because i need only the first 7 string not all of them for filtering data. im already stuck for hours trying to solve this but none of it work at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The "%" symbol in like function refer to character others than something you are searching for, so if you want to search only the first character of the column you need to write it like this :

```
$example = $some_variable->where('kode_rekening', 'LIKE', '5.1.03'.'%')
```

and then you can apply it to all of your 'like' query.
Hope this answer your question

Comment: well im already try this and still not working, this method is working when outside transform() but when inside it, its not working at all